# How to access postgreSQL database from android mobile using python

Tags: android, python-3.x, database, postgresql, pydroid

I wand to access the postgreSQL database from android using Pydroid3 application in my mobile phone. to access postgreSQL database i need to import psycopg2, but android doesn't support this.
can anyone please suggest the way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

With `Android` you typically don't make a hard database connection, unless its a local one.

`psycopg2` doesn't work for the same reason you're not supposed to use `JDBC` . You should talk to a remote database via a `RESTful API`, meaning a server sends you data that it itself retrieves from the database.

So your next step would to create a web site/service that handles `GET` requests. So your app can talk to it, and it can talk to the database.